# Implement jquery into prototypejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I've got this issue with my magento onepage checkout.
I want to implement that when you press complete order it disables the button **only** when everything is filled in and the ToS are checked:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

you press "bestelling plaatsen" and not everything is filled in correctly it still turns gray.

Now I had the idea to implement the the custom code I used to make the button gray in the onepagecheckout script, but the issue is that the code I wrote is Javascript but the onepage checkout script is in prototypejs.

Here's the code from my script;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var btn = $('#onestepcheckout-button-place-order');
    var btnTxt = $('#onestepcheckout-button-place-order span span span');
    var fewSeconds = 10;

    btn.click(function(){
        btn.prop('disabled', true);
        btnTxt.text('Even geduld A.U.B.');
        btn.addClass('disabled');

        setTimeout(function(){
            btn.prop('disabled', false);
            btnTxt.text('Bestelling plaatsen');
            btn.removeClass('disabled');
        }, fewSeconds*1000);
    });
});
```

and this is the code where I think it should be implemented in;

```
Event.observe('onestepcheckout-button-place-order', 'click', function(e) {
    var form = new VarienForm('one-step-checkout-form');
    var validator = new Validation(this.form);  
    if (validator.validate()) {         
        var element = e.element();
        //disable the button
        element.disabled = true;
        $('one-step-checkout-form').submit();
    }
    else {
        //alert('Error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Double post and already answered 23 hours ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25530427/1641941 Why do you feel the need to ask this again?

Comment: It's not the same question, that post is where i asked if someone could translate it to prototype, this post is a question on how i can implement it into my magento onestep checkout

Comment: So the jQuery code you posted in this question and the exact same code in the other question isn't working? You're not saying that you need this translated to prototypejs? (note prototypejs is not prototype). If the jQuery code is working but you don't want to add jQuery library I'd go with the suggestion already answered yesterday. Or make it more clear what it is you're asking because it looks a lot like you're asking how to write the jQuery code in prototypejs. As well as literally stating that in the comment on the answer in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres your code snippet in PrototypeJS

```
document.observe('dom:loaded',function(){
    var fewSeconds = 10;
    $('onestepcheckout-button-place-order').observe('click',function(){
        var textelement = this.down('span span span');
        this.writeAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        textelement.update('Even geduld A.U.B.')
        this.addClassName('disabled');
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.writeAttribute('disabled',false);
            textelement.update('Bestelling plaatsen');
            this.removeClassName('disabled');
        }.bind(this),fewSeconds*1000)
    });

});
```

I made some improvements to make the code more concise

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using the following:

[jQuery.noConflict();](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
// or change $ above to $j
$( "#how-it-works .step" ).hide();

$('.step').each(function( index ) {
$(this).delay( index * 700 ).fadeIn();
});
});
```

A combination of several posts on here. Seems to be really simple and lightweight. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I know about the noConflict syntax but I need the code I either translated to prototype or able to implement in the second code I shared.